# How to mask in Premier Pro CC

Tags: premiere

I'm using Premier Pro CC but at a fairly basic level.  My question is probably a no-brainer for an experienced user. I've searched a lot of other sites and tutorials and haven't found anything that helps.  Here is my dilemma.

I want a constant background, full size, 1080p, but on top of that,(a different track) I want a clip that is a smaller size, like an overlay, that only covers about 50% of the screen size.

I need a mask (or matte) around that top video, so I can zoom and pan on it, yet the borders stay constant, it never consumes more than the original 50% of the screen. If I zoom in 150%, it is still only utilizing 50% of the full screen and the background is still visible.

Does my description make sense?